# multiple instance of usercontrol in same aspx

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, jquery-validate

Hi i have an usercontrol say: ucCustomer.

there are 3 fields inside this usercontrol: 
txtBox1 (required, valid input)
txtBox2(required)
txtBox(required, valid input)

I am using Jquery tabs and in each tab i have a usercontrol.

so when user clicks on continue respective controls inside the usercontrol has to be validated.

I could not achieve grouping for controls. If i have tab1 the controls has to have group_Tab1 and same with tab2 controls have group_Tab2.

So when i click continue i get the controls by group name and validate each fields.

I am using jquery validation for this.
Let me know how i can achieve this.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery and web user controls in aspx,
 the object name change.
 `txtBox2 => UC_XX1_txtBox2
 txtBox2 => UC_XX2_txtBox2` (something like that).
You can select all items by selector and get the childs 
for example:

```
function XXXX()
{
//Get uc Childrens
 $('#UC_XX2_txtBox2 input').each(function () {

     //validate the fields here
    }

//Get uc Childrens
  var list1=$('#UC_XX1_txtBox2 input') 
  for (var i = 0; i < list1.length; i++) {
     //validate the fields here
    }
}
```